# Why does rb.velocity blurrs background?

Tags: unity, 2d, physics, movement, rigidbody

My player controller code is bellow. So is my player inspector. This makes my character move yet it blurs the background, but when I use  `transform.position.x = transform.right * speed * Time.DeltaTime` it moves without blurring the background. However I'd prefer moving the character using the physics system, to avoid complications with collisions, etc.. What is going on?

```
[SerializeField] public float speed;
[SerializeField] public float jumpForce;

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private CharacterAnimationsAn animationScript;
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    animationScript = GetComponent<CharacterAnimationsAn>();
    gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);
    animationScript.SetRunning(true);
}
```

[image: Player Inspector]

Maybe it might be related to the Script that make the Camera follow the Player?

```
myDistanceToFllowerDifference = gameObject.transform.position - objectTofollow.transform.position;

gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(objectTofollow.transform.position.x + myDistanceToFllowerDifference.x, gameObject.transform.position.y, gameObject.transform.position.z);
```

I have no processing stack, my camera inspector is bellow:

[image: Camera Inspector]

I also have a parralax script working on the background which has an inner working almost identical to this: [Parallax Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zit45k6CUMk)

I should correct that it might not be a blur but actually an effect similar to a low frame rate on the background, while the player and everything show no such effect. Unfortunately I can't actually provide you with an image of the effect, as I'm not authorized to do so.

Comment: It sounds like you have motion vectors and motion blur enabled on your camera/post effect stack. Can you show us a screenshot or video of the effect, and information about how you've configured your rendering?

Comment: "Unfortunately I can't actually provide you with an image of the effect, as I'm not authorized to do so." Then reproduce the problem in a new project using placeholder public domain assets, so that you don't need authorization to show it.